# In Manjaro-i3, how can I run software installed via wine?

Tags: manjaro, i3, wine

I have just switched to i3 from KDE. Under KDE, all wine software was just listed as regular software I could launch from the start menu or desktop. In i3, however, no software I installed via wine pops up when I hit the `windows key + d` shortcut and start typing in the name. The only way I can launch such software is to navigate to the installation directory with the terminal, then type in `wine ExecutableName.exe`. Surely, there must be an easier solution to this, or should I write a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll solve your problem:

[j4-dmenu-desktop](https://github.com/enkore/j4-dmenu-desktop)

You can add it to another keyboard shortcut, `window key + alt + d` for example. It searches and executes .desktop files. So it can be used for all .desktop application launchers. Since the wine apps could be found in your start menu, they must have .desktop launchers, as ordinary linux apps. They'll be used and executed by j4-dmenu-desktop.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

**Krunner** described [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/plasma-desktop/krunner.html) and [here](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner) can be used to run any application, documents or switch to an opened window.